# String modification in php

Tags: php

I would like to know how to change a string pattern into something else.  I'm setting up a small forum and would like to embed youtube video whenever someone enters the link into the textarea part of the forum.  Youtube video links look like this;

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=examplevideo
```

But, I would like to change this string to look like this;

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/examplevideo">
</iframe>
```

So, I would be swapping out everything except for the "examplevideo"  string.  Since this link would be included with other text from the textarea part of the form, my guess is that I would have to set up an if statement to look for anything that says "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="  Would I use a string comparison for this?  How would this work?

Comment: can't you use: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) ?

Comment: You're not just replacing, you're appending the html around it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to echo the result:

```
if(strpos($url,"youtube.com/watch?v=")){
    echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="';
    echo str_replace('/watch?v=','/embed/',$url);
    echo '"></iframe>';
}else{
    echo $url;
}
```

`strpos` manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
`str_replace` manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @Kimomaru I added `str_replace` to use the embed url instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simple regex solution to get everything after `?v=`

```
$video_name = preg_replace('/^.*\?v=/', '', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=examplevideo');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Regular Expressions:

```
// $url is 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/examplevideo'
$url = preg_replace('/https?\:\/\/www.youtube.com/watch\?v=(.*)/i', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1', $url);
```

What this does is, it looks for a string starting with 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' (I added the '?' so that it matches both http and https), takes whatever follows and appends this to 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.